# Rebase an old branch into a new one in a local git repository

Tags: git, rebase

I would like to rebase a local git repository from:

```
A - B - C - D - E - F- G

        \ 
         P
```

to:

```
A - B - P - C - D - E - F- G
```

There are no dependencies between P and the later on commits.

Comment: It's usually depicted as `A - B - P - C' - D' - E' - F' - G'` to show that commit `C'` is not the same commit as `C`. Anyway, this is exactly what rebase is for, so what part of it are you having trouble with?

Comment: @hvd: psst. I guess the author simply would like to C' be actually the same commit as C that's why s/he did not marked it so ;)

Comment: Yes, the point was to maintain the same history since P did not have interferences with the rest (if it had, one could resolve them manually, but it can get complicated…) I had never had this issue before. The answer underneath (git rebase P master --onto P) works perfect and it does not mess up newer commits :)

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that your `P` commit is on a branch named `P` and your longer sequence is on `master`.  You get exactly what you want if you say:

```
    git rebase P master --onto P
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I was afraid of messing up with the newer commits wit rebasing that way. Good to know this! Thanks again! :)